# Unable to load PDFBox PDDocument using inputstream

Tags: java, pdf, inputstream, pdfbox

I've been trying to collect hyperlinks from parsing a pdf file. 
So, for the process, I'd to load inputstream of a file URL.
While generating the PDFDocument, I'm unable to get the required PDFDocument as it always tends to null.

While using locally like,

```
PDDocument doc;
String src = "C:\\Users\\Rajen\\Desktop\\473569-event.pdf";
doc = PDDocument.load(new File(src));
```

It is working well.

**BUT**
Trying any url,

```
InputStream iS = new URL(URLPDFLink).openStream();
doc = PDDocument.load(iS);
```

It is not working.

Could it be memory issue?
The below link file is few kb Only.

Is there any solutions or enhancement for this?

**UPDATE**

I couldn't even collect the issue type and error type.
The code directly jumps to finally block.

[image: Image finally]

[Connection URL](https://solutions-selectsite-documents.s3.amazonaws.com/Sourcingevent/473569-event.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ5HNJE5DFBZ5ONSA&Expires=1517565328&Signature=oCnIBd9w%2FtAQxaoCACgSRI4ngmk%3D)

Comment: can you paste an exception you are getting

Comment: Please answer Bruno's question why you previously used the `itext` tag for a `pdfbox` question.

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse 
I was hoping for the possible suggestion fomr people as they might be familiar with pdf. So, I happened to include both names earlier. 
This is the only reason.

Comment: Please note that this reason is considered abuse by the Stack Overflow community, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/poisoning-of-api-related-tags-on-stack-overflow and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11189/what-to-do-about-tag-abuse and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140977/tag-abuse-and-tag-editing and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347806/is-tag-spamming-or-blatant-mis-tagging-a-legitimate-reason-to-downvote-a-questio

Comment: @rzenks 1) Please tell what PDFBox version you're using - hopefully 2.0.8. 2) your url points to an XML file and throws an exception.

Comment: wow.. 3 answers and a "what kind of a developer does that make you" for a misused tag, I wonder what would have happened if he misused 2 tags